# trying to teach myself python, stuck during one chapter of this book, very simple question

Tags: python

```
from sys import argv

script, user_name=argv
```

that's part of the program i'm trying to run and I don't think any more is necessary. I try and run it by typing into terminal:

```
python exl.py script user_name
```

That should work, right? I know this is pretty simple, but I am really stuck. Also I don't completely understand what I'm doing there. The book I'm using is dealing with paramaters and unpacking right now and I don't completely get it. An explanation would be awesome.

Thanks

Comment: Next time you should post the error message too. I'm guessing it's `ValueError: too many values to unpack`

Answer (score 3):

`sys.argv[0]` is the name of your script (in this case `exl.py`).  You don't pass the literal "script".

You can easily try this with a test program:

```
import sys
print sys.argv
```

Answer (score 1):

`sys.argv` is a list containing the name of the script and each of the command line parameters.  In the case of running `python exl.py script user_name`, `sys.argv` will have a length of 3 (the script (exl.py) and two parameters (script and user_name).  Your script expects `argv` to have two entries (script, user_name) not three, so fails.  Try `python exl.py user_name` instead.

Here's an example you can type at the interactive prompt:

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84297, Aug 24 2010, 18:46:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> L = [1,2,3] # make a 3-element list.
>>> a,b = L     # but only try to unpack 2 elements.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack
>>> a,b,c = L   # now try three elements
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
>>> c
3
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try using an index slice!

```
from sys import argv
script, user_name=argv[:2]
```

Basically, argv is an array that contains the arguments passed to the program at the command line. In this case the array would contain [exl.py, script, user_name].
When you unpack an array, you need to have a place to unpack them to. In your case you are only supplying two variables to unpack an array with three items into.

In case you were wondering, array slices work like this:
a[x:y] where a is the array, x is the index to begin the slice, and y is the place to stop. In the above example, I am starting at index 1 (between exl.py and script) and ending at the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

argv is an array, so you need to do something like:
script = argv[1]
user_name = argv[2]

Note that argv[0] is set to the script name (see this link http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html)